# What was it that Yevon did to the Al Bhed?

Tags: final-fantasy

In *Final Fantasy X*, after being transported to Bikinel Desert by Sin and reunited, Rikku goes to tell the party where they are

> **Rikku**: i know where we are, but you have to keep it a secret, especially from Yevonites
>   **Wakka**: What are you accusing Yevon of this time?
>   **Rikku**: Yevon did something really terrible to us before

however all Rikku says at Home is that Sin destroyed the island they came from and it was her father Cid who gathered the separated Al Bhed to build Home. i don't recall Rikku explaining what Yevon did to the Al Bhed, is it stated anywhere what Yevon did?

Comment: Well, Yevon created Sin, so there's always that. I don't expect that's what she meant, though.

Comment: I think she just wanted to keep it a secret because Al-Bhed use machina which is strictly forbidden by Yevon.

Comment: @Alchemist the way Rikku looks when she says Yevon did something terrible to them in the past it seems to indicate they did something worse then that usual hypocritical racism that the Al Bhed suffer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While exactly what Yevon did to the Al Bhed was never revealed in Final Fantasy X, this information was eventually revealed in [Final Fantasy X-2.5](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_X-2.5_%7EEien_no_Daish%C5%8D%7E).

> Final Fantasy X-2.5 is a novel sequel to Final Fantasy X-2 written by Kazushige Nojima who had written the scenario for Final Fantasy X and Final Fantasy X-2. It was released on December 26th, 2013 to commemorate the release of Final Fantasy X/X-2 HD Remaster.

Yevon essentially blamed the [Al Bhed](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Al_Bhed) for Sin's appearance, performed a mass execution, followed by outcasting them.

> **Final Fantasy X-2.5 ~Eien no Daishō~**
>
> The origins of the Al Bhed are revealed in the sequel novel to Final Fantasy X-2. There was once a mechanic called Alb who created a race called Bedohls, humans who could not use magic but excelled at wielding machina, and used them to combat a Zanarkandian mage. Their weapons were so powerful they were kept under surveillance at all times. It's speculated that their power might have been the catalyst for the Machina War. **After the Yevon religion was established, the Bedohls were blamed for the emergence of Sin and executed in numbers, thereby casting them out of society. The surviving Bedohls were later renamed the Al Bhed, a corrupted mesh of their original name and their creator's name.**